# Simplifying a product with indices by implementing a rule

Tags: simplifying-expressions, packages

I want to simplify a product of two operators including indices. Let's say my operators are

$$
\mathcal{O}^{\mu \nu, \alpha \beta} = -p^2 \left( \eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta} + \eta^{\mu \beta} \eta^{\nu \alpha} - \eta^{\mu \nu} \eta^{\alpha \beta}\right)
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{D}_{\alpha \beta, \sigma \lambda} = A(p) \left( \eta_{\alpha \sigma} \eta_{\beta \lambda} + \eta_{\alpha \lambda}\eta_{\beta \sigma}\right) + B(p)\eta_{\alpha \beta}\eta_{\sigma \lambda}.
$$

Of course, I should obey the contraction rule, i.e; $\eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta_{\alpha \sigma} = \delta^{\mu}_{\sigma}$ in the process.

I am new to Mathematica, so I don't know how to do this. **Is there a simple way one can suggest or is there a Mathematica package that deals with this kind of calculations?**

Actually,  if someone shows how to define these operators in Mathematica and how to implement the contraction rule, it will be better for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of computing the result that you seek.

Define the operators. I have used a convention in which upper/lower indices are given as first/second arguments.

```
Clear[op1, op2]

op1[mu_, nu_, alf_, bet_] := 
  -p^2 (eta[{mu, alf}, {}] eta[{nu, bet}, {}] + 
        eta[{mu, bet}, {}] eta[{nu, alf}, {}] - 
        eta[{mu, nu}, {}] eta[{alf, bet}, {}])

op2[alf_, bet_, sig_, lam_] := 
  a[p] (eta[{}, {alf, sig}] eta[{}, {bet, lam}] + 
        eta[{}, {alf, lam}] eta[{}, {bet, sig}]) + 
  b[p] eta[{}, {alf, bet}] eta[{}, {sig, lam}]
```

Define some rules for manipulating the operators. I have assumed that `eta` is a metric tensor so it is symmetric. I have aimed for clarity, so I may have defined more rules than are actually needed to solve this particular problem.

```
Clear[eta, del]

eta /: eta[{mu_, alf_} | {alf_, mu_}, {}] eta[{}, {alf_, sig_} | {sig_, alf_}] := del[{mu}, {sig}];
eta[{lam_, mu_}, {}] /; ! OrderedQ[{lam, mu}] := eta[{mu, lam}, {}];
eta[{}, {lam_, mu_}] /; ! OrderedQ[{lam, mu}] := eta[{}, {mu, lam}];

del /: del[{nu_}, {bet_}] eta[{mu_, bet_} | {bet_, mu_}, {}] := eta[{mu, nu}, {}];
del /: del[{alf_}, {sig_}] eta[{}, {alf_, lam_} | {lam_, alf_}] := eta[{}, {sig, lam}];
del[{bet_}, {bet_}] := 4;
```

Evaluate the product of the operators.

```
op1[mu, nu, alf, bet] op2[alf, bet, sig, lam] // Expand // Simplify

(*
  2 p^2 (b[p] eta[{}, {lam, sig}] eta[{mu, nu}, {}] - 
         a[p] (del[{mu}, {sig}] del[{nu}, {lam}] + 
               del[{mu}, {lam}] del[{nu}, {sig}] - 
               eta[{}, {lam, sig}] eta[{mu, nu}, {}]))
*)
```

To display this is a more easily readable format use the `` Notation` `` package.

```
<< Notation`
```

Define various notations to display expressions in a format that is closer to the way a mathematician would write them. This looks messy when it is written out in `InputForm` (as it is here so it can be copied/pasted). You would normally enter these expressions using the palette that pops up when you load the `` Notation` `` package.

Edit: I found that for this copy/paste to work correctly you have to copy/paste into an input cell, then select the cell bracket and evaluate the menu command Cell / Convert To / Raw InputForm, then evaluate the resulting input cell. Of course, this problem doesn't happen when you use the `` Notation` `` palette.

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[\(\[Eta]\^\(a_\ b_\)\)] 
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[\(eta[\(\({a_, b_}\), \({}\)\)]\)]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[\(\[Eta]\_\(a_\ b_\)\)]
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[\(eta[\(\({}\), \({a_, b_}\)\)]\)]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[\(\[Delta]\_\[Beta]_\%\[Alpha]_\)]
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[\(del[\(\({\[Alpha]_}\), \({\[Beta]_}\)\)]\)]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[Alpha]"] 
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper["alf"]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[Beta]"] 
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper["bet"]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[Mu]"] 
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper["mu"]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[Lambda]"] 
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper["lam"]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[Nu]"] 
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper["nu"]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[Sigma]"] 
  \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper["sig"]]
```

Now reevaluate `op1[mu, nu, alf, bet] op2[alf, bet, sig, lam] // Expand // Simplify` to obtain the "pretty printed" version of the result. Note that I haven't checked that this result is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that much. This will definitely help me a lot.